# extra space above table in tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE text editor. It has a feature of inserting table inside the editor. The problem is, when I display the table after the user clicks submit, there are some blank spaces above the table, which don't seem to go away. This doesn't happen when I type in normal text, etc but only with tables.

I have researched about this, and saw a lot of answers on how the tables add extra line break tags and that we just need to remove them. But in my case i can't see no line break tags in source code that the tinyMCE generates.

Comment: http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:force_br_newlines

Comment: Without seeing some running code it will be hard to provide you any real details.  I am assuming that "after the user clicks submit" you are rendering the content outside of TinyMCE and it looks different than it does inside TinyMCE?  If so that is almost certainly CSS related.  What you really need to do is create a minimal, complete, verifiable example that shows what you are seeing:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, but I actually was able to solve the problem. What I was doing is, I was storing the table in a database and retrieving it using PHP, And displaying it using, PHP 'echo', and I was also using nl2br() function along with echo. This is where the problem is. This nl2br function was adding line breaks inside all the lines of 'table' tag.

Removing this nl2br() function and just using echo solved the problem.